# Can we use one-two instead of first-second?

Tags: spoken-english, numbers

I was listening a song. The lines are,

> One, my last album flopped
>   Two, it wasn't my time
>   Three, my f***in' mama's selling my pajamas online

The use of One, two three is quite new to me. I have heard phrases like,

First, I did this. Second I went there.

Firstly I want money, and secondly peace.

My question is when to use *One-Two-Three* and when to use *First-Second-Third* and when to use *Firstly-Secondly-Thirdly*?

Comment: FYI Song lyrics are often very informal, and (like poetry) often bend the rules.

Comment: @zwol Are the rules bend in the case I've mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 7):

Ordinals are used to describe something's order in a sequence. These are the "first, second, third" words you have mentioned. However, numbers by themselves can be used to denote points on a list.

Therefore, we should use ordinals when describing things to do in sequence:

> First, we need to till the soil. Second, we'll plant the flower seeds. After that, it's just a matter of waiting.

On the other hand, if someone has multiple, separate points to address, they might verbally number them for emphasis:

> Speaker A: What's wrong with you?
>
> Speaker B: Well, for one, my feet are killing me after standing around all day in these heels. Two, I'm starting to get a migrane. Three, I just found out the train is out of service today so I'll have to pay for a ride home.

Ordinals can be used in the second example, too, but it implies that the points are listed in order of most important to least important. Adding -ly to the end just turns the ordinal into its adverb form.

Answer (score 2):

They are interchangeable.  Use whichever you are accustomed to, or whichever sounds good to you at the time.  In addition, you can count using letters of the alphabet.

Comment: I don't think they are interchangeable. As Crazy eyes has told, First-Second are used when there is an order associated. On the other hand when we use One-two there is no order and we can state the sentence starting with _two_ at first also by just rephrasing it with _one_ in place of _two_.

Comment: Nah, it's a in one's imagination.  Wishful thinking.  I can say "first" and then something just because it came *first* to my head to say, and then say "second" simply because I just thought of it *after* the one I just expressed.

Comment: Can we say _" **One**, we need to till the soil. **two**, we'll plant the flower seeds. After that, it's just a matter of waiting_"?

Comment: Why can't we?  The *order* is expressed in either "First, second..." or in "one, two..." or in "A, b, ..."  It would be silly to say that "first, second" implies the order, while "one, two" doesn't.

Comment: I still have some doubt. E.g. _Bob: Why didn't they let you watch the movie? Joe: One, I look small. Two, I was clean shaved._ In this scenario I can switch _one_ with _two_ --> "_Joe: One, I was clean shaved. Two, I look small._". Now consider "_First, we need to till the soil. Second, we'll plant the flower seeds._" Here I can't switch first with second because there is an order associated. My question is can we change _First_ with _Second_ in some scenario?

Comment: What you're comparing is not the use of "first, second" versus "one, two", but the ability of Joe to list his perceived deficiencies with no particular order versus a very specific order of operations for growing flowers.   Now, let's try and see how the meaning changes (if at all) if you use "first, second" with Joe's statements and "one, two" with flower growing instructions.  I assert that since the order exists in "one, two", there will be no difference.

Comment: Perhaps I am getting you. "First-Second" or "One-two" don't make the _order_. It is perhaps the context which makes the order. If I use First-Second for Joe's deficiencies then I can switch First with Second -- because there is no order associated.

Comment: But still we can't use First-Second in the following example: "_Well, for one, my feet are killing me after standing around all day in these heels. Two, I'm starting to get a migrane. Three, I just found out the train is out of service today so I'll have to pay for a ride home._" Replacing with first second sounds odd --> _"Well, first, my feet are killing me after standing around all day in these heels. Second, I'm starting to get a migrane. Third, I just found out the train is out of service today so I'll have to pay for a ride home._"